# Add custom action on clipboard option

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to add option on clipboard like Chrome has when we select URL
[image]

Is it possible to add option of my application in Clipboard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Xamarin. But in native Android it's done in this way.
Add an intent filter to an Activity in your manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ProcessTextActivity"
    android:label="@string/process_text_action_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Text from `android:label` will be shown in context menu

It's described in details in [this Android developers blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999)

Another question on the same topic: [How to use the new Android M feature of "Text Selection" to be offered from outside of your app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518089)

Answer (score 0):

For each `TextView` you want to customize the menu you need to pass your own `android.view.ActionMode.Callback` to `TextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback` function.

In your implementation of `android.view.ActionMode.Callback` you are free to add/edit/remove items as you wish.

UPDATE: Didn’t realize that this issue is on Xamarin platform.
I guess the answer should be similar.