# How to add new item to Android Long Press on Edit Text?

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, long-press

Is it possible to add new item to the list which appear when user long press on an empty EditText view? Just like Copy / Paste / Select / Select All, I want to add "Translate". How can I implement this?

I tried using [setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(android.view.ActionMode.Callback))
but it did not work for EditText view.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518089/how-to-use-the-new-android-m-feature-of-text-selection-to-be-offered-from-outs   I think it answers your question